# Ubuntu 13.04 Online Accounts Settings not opening

Tags: online-accounts, system-settings

When I go to system settings and click on online accounts, the window for the settings shows up for about half a second before disappearing. Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

Comment: Try starting from a Terminal: `online-accounts-preferences`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also getting this and followed a thread of bugs until I got to this one:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/+bug/1177285

Which actually shows that a fix has been [committed](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/3.6.4-0ubuntu4.1), but it is in the 'proposed' repositories.

1. go to 'software and updates';
2. on the 'Updates' tab check the Pre-release repository option (raring-proposed for me);
3. open your favourite package manager, I did it with synaptic;
4. reload/refresh your package info;
5. search for 'empathy'
   -> there should now be a 3.6.4-0ubuntu4.1 package available (to trump my previous 3.6.4-0ubuntu4)
6. install it!

I then also disabled the pre-released updated as I didn't want to upgrade other programs to the versions in there.

1. kill the running empathy (via system monitor)
2. start up empathy again.

I think I also restarted gnome-shell (alt+f2, r [enter]) somewhere in there but I'm not sure that's necessary.

Hope that works for you.

Comment: Seem to be having a problem updating - I tried from the command line and got this:

Comment: sudo apt-get install empathy/raring-proposed
First stuff ok...
Selected version '3.6.4-0ubuntu4.1' (Ubuntu:13.04/raring-proposed [amd64]) for 'empathy'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 empathy : Depends: empathy-common (= 3.6.4-0ubuntu4.1) but 3.6.4-0ubuntu4 is to be installed

Comment: Recommends: nautilus-sendto-empathy but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: mcp-account-manager-uoa but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: I can try Package->Force version in Synaptic but that will delete a bunch of packages....is that a good thing to do?